# How to check if a field in a table already exists?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

my question is very simple:
i have a SQL Table with a column name 'lastname' with fields lastname1,lastname2,lastname3...

In my c# code, i have a method that inserts in the table a row only if the field of the column lastname is not present in the table. This method in input has lastname, so for my INSERT is a parameter.

How can i compare and conseguently check if the field lastname is already in table?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do if the value already exists?  Lastname seems like an odd choice for a "unique" field.

Answer (score 2):

You should always use [unique constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in the table if a field must be unique. On that way you prevent duplicates always, even if the input was directly from SSMS or another application.

Then the easiest would be to handle the sql-exception that is raised according to it's number.

```
....

try
{
    int inserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
} catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == 2601)
    {
        // show meaningful error message
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot insert duplicate key row in object"); 
    }
    else
        throw;
}

....
```

Comment: Agree on the constraint part but checking if something exists is almost always better than shoot blindly and handle exceptions.

Comment: @banging: depends on how how likely it is. A check might have an implicit race condition.

Comment: You are right, but maybe i have not clearly explained my issue. I want to insert the row if not exists, but if exists, i however had the possibility to UPDATE the row. In my code i've wrote a simple method(called RecordExist) that return true if the field is in the table, false if not. So i have 2 different situation to manage.

Comment: @OmnipresentPerception: Then you could use an "Upsert" stored-procedure. For example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/bf6d89/how-to-implement-upsert-method-in-C-Sharp/ (look at the first comment, not the article)

Answer (score 0):

This SQL will insert a new record only if the value isn't already in the table:

```
INSERT INTO Your_Table ( LastName )
SELECT @NewLastName
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM Your_Table WHERE LastName = @NewLastName )
```

Comment: unfortunatly in my c# code i have a statement with a INSERT that i can't modify... For my goal,the way is by code, not by TSQL. I'm thinking a sort of campare with my input parameter of the method and the value of the record in table, but i'm not able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two option one is from sql side another way is from code behind.

unfortunately you can't change your sql code i agree with @David.

from code behind you have to do something like this.

First you have to select all the data from your table and check that data. something like this.

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con; //Your connection string"
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from table1"; // your query
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; i > dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["LastName"]) == Lastname)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count > 0)
    {
        //insert code for data
    }
    else
    {
        var script = "alert('"+ Lastname + "already exist.');";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Alert", script, true);
        // or you can use here your Update statement
    }
```

May this will help you and you can understand.